# How can be done a SQL query which is not implemented inside the browser interface?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, postgresql, apache

With the rise of home office I have to went and do all class of stuff via a web interface inside a database, the problem is that the developer did not add a field or page to formulate a custom sql query.

I understand that the php query parser its on files located in the server side (process.php and all that) so these cant be modified (and I dont intent to do that). The idea is to view/know how many fields are inside a certain database, since the work requires the existence of 2 specific fields that via the web interface does not seem to appear, and to know if these fields exists or not, so the data can be inserted in an accord format (and to request to the developer add it).

I have the legit access to the server, so how can the sql query be piped directly to the server outside the web interface?, or, since Im a valid user, a terminal session can be launched to check the structure?

The developer team is not responding, and left us with some issues,but this is the most needed.

- Web server: Apache (dont know the version but guessing its from the
  last 2.4.4x branches)
- Server: Some flavor of linux.
- SQL :Postgresql 11.x/12.x (but not sure, it can be mysql)

Thanks.

Comment: There are web-based query interfaces for PostgreSQL (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients#Web_Clients) but the developers need to enable these, so one way or the other you need to get them to respond. Escalate to their manager if necessary.

Comment: That was the main idea, but as the developer and managers left us with no support suddenly.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server? If so, establish a tunnel connection. `ssh -L 5431:127.0.0.1:5432 user@server` and connect through that using psql.

Comment: The ssh  is supposed to be active, Im going to check it out.

Comment: @clamp, it is active, but would the user  be the same for ssh than for web login/postgresql?

Comment: It's really unlikely that the ssh user, the web user, and the postgresql user would be the same. Possible, but only if the developers were pretty negligent about security. But it sounds like they just ghosted you, if the entire developer team _and_ their manager disappeared without leaving you with access to your servers. Sorry to hear that. For future projects, you should make sure you have access at all times.